# Printing CSV data

Tags: python-3.x, csv, printing

Wanted to print csv data in single line.

**CSVFile.txt:**

```
abc|xyz|111
def|uvw|222
```

**Python 3.x code:**

```
with open(csvfile, "r") as csvdata:
    for line in csvdata:
        fields = line.split("|")
        for data in fields:
            # do some processing and then
            print(data)
```

This prints the data as

```
abc
xyz
111
def
uvw
222
```

Want to print data in straight line as

```
abc, xyz, 111
def, uvw, 222
```

Comment: What is `fields`? Is it a single row or the whole file?

Comment: updated my question with more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your processed `data` in a list and print them together when you are finished processing each row instead:

```
...
row = []
for data in fields:
    # do some processing and then
    row.append(str(data))
print(", ".join(row))
...
```